# Zend Form: Custom validator isvalid()

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I have to create my custom `FORM:isvalid()` function in my `form` like below, because I have to check if one of  these 2 fields are at least filled out:

```
class Products_AddForm extends Zend_Form {

public function isValid($data)
{

    // Check special post data
    $pzn_val = $data['PZN'];
    $mar_val = $data['PZO'];

    if(empty($pzn_val) && empty($mar_val)) {
        $this->getSubForm('sub1')->getElement('PZN')->setErrors(array('PZN or PZO needed'));
        $this->getSubForm('sub2')->getElement('PZO')->setErrors(array('PZN or PZO needed'));
    }

    // Standard validation
    return parent::isValid($data);

}
```

The errors for `PZN` and `PZO` will only fire if another error (other field) will be found.
How can I get the `form error`?
Field `PZN` and `PZO` are defined as `not required`.

TIA
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
public function isValid($data) {
    $isValid = parent::isValid($data); 
    // Check special post data
    $pzn_val = $data['PZN'];
    $mar_val = $data['PZO'];

    if(empty($pzn_val) && empty($mar_val)) {
        $this->getSubForm('sub1')->getElement('PZN')->setErrors(array('PZN or PZO needed'));
        $this->getSubForm('sub2')->getElement('PZO')->setErrors(array('PZN or PZO needed'));
        $isValid = false;
    }    

    return $isValid;
}
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked. You could mark it as Accepted answer..  :)

Comment: need to wait 5 minutes... 'you can accept an answer in 5 minutes' ^^